# DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "balances" or "balanceOf"?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, compilation

I have gone through the similar questions and weirdly, none of them seem to solve this problem.

I am creating a simple token contract

```
contract Token {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
    uint public totalSupply = 1000;
    string public name = "test1";
    string public symbol = "t1";
    uint public decimals = 3;
    // An address type variable is used to store ethereum accounts.
    address public owner;
    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    
    /**
     * Contract initialization.
     */
    constructor() {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address acc) external view returns(uint) {
        return balances[acc];
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        //require(balances[msg.sender] >= value, 'balance too low'); // WORKS
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low'); // DOESN'T WORK
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

As mentioned, the `balaces[]` method works and the contract compiles successfully but with `balanceOf()`, I get

```
% npx hardhat compile
Compiling 1 file with 0.8.2
Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
--> contracts/testtoken1.sol


DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "balances" or "balanceOf"?
  --> contracts/testtoken1.sol:30:17:
   |
30 |         require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^


Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make method `balanceOf` as `public` or replace:

```
require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
```

with:

```
require(this.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
```

Answer (score 1):

`balanceOf()` function is set as `external` function which cannot be called within the contract. Set it `public` instead and it should work fine